# Like a Facebook Page using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I need to put a custom image for F Like. But it seems the only way to do it is by using Facebook APP, asking users permission and liking it via PHP SDK.

The last part is the one that does not work for me. Permission granted by user is "publish_actions" and "user_likes" (user_likes is just to know whether the user has already liked the page or not which works fine)

The code that I am trying to debug is.

```
$facebook->api('/me/likes', 'post', array('url'=>'<URL to Facebook page>'));
```

Any thoughts? I have tried enough searches and read forums, but can't find answer to "Is it possible or not" and if it is where am I wrong

The response I am getting is
"(#200) App does not have permission to make this call"

Comment: You can not like a Facebook page via API.

Answer (score 1):

In order to publish Like on a Facebook page, you must use [Like button social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/).

One way of publishing Likes on objects is by using [Open Graph Like feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/#publishing). This requires a `publish_actions` permission and the graph URL looks like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB ID]/og.likes
object=OG_OBJECT_URL&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

However, this currently doesn't support Facebook Pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see wheather facebook access is disabled for u or not